# NiFi ConsumeKafkaRecord and PublishKafkaRecord - how to pass headers?

Tags: apache-nifi, kafka-consumer-api

I’m trying to build NiFi flow where I copy topic as is from one Kafka cluster to another.

The messages in this topic have headers of Long type and I can’t find a good way to pass them. Currently, they are passed as some wrong encoded string.

I’m using the latest versions ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_6 and PublishKafkaRecord_2_6.

Is there any way to do it?
Thanks.